# listview checkbox binding wpf MVVM

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm

I am trying to get the bool value of the checkbox present in the Listview. I am binding to a bool public property "Assignm" in the view model. I tried the below binding pattern but the problem is if i select one checkbox it selects all checkboxes and vice versa. I think this is because relativesource is listview and it works on complete listview. I also tried changing the relative source to ListviewItem but that didn't trigger anything. Can someone help me please. Do i need to change something here ?

```
  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
  <CheckBox  Tag="{Binding MU_Identifier}" IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.Assignm, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}">
 </CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: The Assignm property should be in the item class (where MU_Identifier is). The Binding would be `IsChecked="{Binding Assignm}"`.

Comment: But is it a good idea to add another property to my item class (Entity Model) even though this bool value is not stored in the Database. ? I have web client architecture application. @Clemens

Comment: A better practice is to create another model for this purpose, that is this model includes the property needed to be bound. Then create a mapping between the two models.

Answer (score 1):

Because your binding for `IsChecked` property is `Assignm` property which seems to be one property of your view model.

If there is a boolean property named `Assignm` for the data model of the `DataSource` of ListView, then just change the binding like this: `{Binding Assignm}`, as `Tag` property does.

Comment: I don't have a bool property in my data model so i created a public bool property. But as others also suggested the same i think i will have to add a new bool property to my entity model and the worst part is this value won't be stored in the database. i am using this checkbox to select the MU_Identifier and assign it to the users.

Answer (score 0):

All your items are bounded to a single property, so when one item changes a property in your context it changes on other items.

To provide correct work all your items from ItemsSource should have property IsChecked. 
Check this [Example](http://www.licensespot.com/blog/wpf-listview-checkbox)